# Mechanise Post headers

Tags: ruby, mechanize

How can I see what headers are being passed with a mechanize post request?

In other words, if I am using a.post url, I would like to see the request headers that were sent in the post request.

Comment: You can connect through a proxy like charles or fiddler and check the request there.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a `pre_connect_hook` and check the request headers there.

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new do |a|
  a.pre_connect_hooks << lambda do |a, request|
    p request.to_hash # convert the request to header hash and dump it
  end
end

agent.post 'http://stackoverflow.com'

# {"accept-encoding"=>["gzip,deflate,identity"], "accept"=>["*/*"], ... }
```

Comment: this works. is there another way, or is this the only workaround?

Comment: @YevgenyYurgenson why?